# Connecting Atoti to Oracle database

Tags: atoti

I want to make a connection to an Oracle database and I have found the following method in the docs:
https://docs.atoti.io/latest/lib/atoti.store.html?highlight=jdbc#atoti.store.Store.load_sql

I call this method with something like this: `my_store.load_sql(url, query, username=my_username, password=my_password)`
And I use a URL with this form: `'jdbc:XX.XX.XX.XX:YYYY/ZZZZ'`, but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No driver provided and cannot infer it from URL.
```

I also created this config with a path to a jdbc jar file in my SQL Developer folder, but the error persists:

```
my_jdbc = 'ojdbc8.jar'
tt.config.create_config(extra_jars = my_jdbc)
```

Does anyone know how I can solve it or have any example of loading stores from an Oracle database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `atoti-sql` plugin comes with the Oracle driver so you don't need to add an extra jar to the config. However you do need to pass the driver when calling `my_store.load_sql`. These can be found in the `atoti_sql.drivers` module.
In your case since you are using an Oracle database, the correct code should be something like:

```
my_store.load_sql(
  url,
  query,
  username=username,
  password=mypassword,
  driver=atoti_sql.drivers.ORACLE
)
```